# Get Array With Array but it's goes array in array

Tags: ios, arrays, gps, parse-platform, mkpolyline

I have data on database like this.

```
["{37.331622, -122.030337}","{37.331593, -122.03051}","{37.331554, -122.030681}","{37.331383, -122.030757}","{37.33108, -122.030772}","{37.330798, -122.030729}","{37.330636, -122.030636}"]
```

Then i try to query data from database by following code.

```
- (void)updateLocations {
    CGFloat kilometers = self.radius/1000.0f;
    //PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Session"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:@"t2udAri048"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"objects %@",objects);
            NSLog(@"path %@",[objects valueForKey:@"Path"]);
            NSArray *pointsArray = [objects valueForKey:@"Path"];;
            NSInteger pointsCount = pointsArray.count;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[pointsCount];

            for(int i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
                CGPoint p = CGPointFromString(pointsArray[i]);
                pointsToUse[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(p.x,p.y);
            }

            MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsToUse count:pointsCount];
            [self.mapView addOverlay:myPolyline];
            //NSLog(@"Drawed %@",pointsArray);
        }
    }];
}
```

I get the value of [objects valueForKey:@"Path"]

> (
>           (
>           "{37.331622, -122.030337}",
>           "{37.331593, -122.03051}",
>           "{37.331554, -122.030681}",
>           "{37.331383, -122.030757}",
>           "{37.33108, -122.030772}",
>           "{37.330798, -122.030729}",
>           "{37.330636, -122.030636}"
>       ) )

But i want it to

> (
>           "{37.331622, -122.030337}",
>           "{37.331593, -122.03051}",
>           "{37.331554, -122.030681}",
>           "{37.331383, -122.030757}",
>           "{37.33108, -122.030772}",
>           "{37.330798, -122.030729}",
>           "{37.330636, -122.030636}"
>       )

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if `objects` is an *array* of one element, which is an object with the "Path"
property. In that case you should replace

```
NSArray *pointsArray = [objects valueForKey:@"Path"];
```

by

```
NSArray *pointsArray = [objects[0] valueForKey:@"Path"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have the objectId. If that is the case, you use getObjectWithId. This will return only the object you want.

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Session"];

[query getObjectWithId:@"hr46gjh45"];

Your example returns an array of objects; in this case the array has only one object (but it is still an array). In that case you must first retrieve the object from the array.